# Play hls m3u8 format in nextjs

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

How can I use hls m3u8 format in nextjs

I tried with video.js CDN but I couldn't achieve it. Hls.js and react player are not compatible with the last version.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example at this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hgv7za-ezygog.

Currently, it is working for me with the sample m3u8 file located at https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8.

If you encounter a specific error, please provide more details, such as the console log, etc.

Comment: not working the video isn't playing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ImBIOS I will update it asap